# Escaping characters by passing an array to a function by reference

Tags: php, reference

```
function escape_all(&$val){
    foreach($val as $key=>$value){
        $value =  mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
}
```

`escape_all($trimmed_user);`

The unwanted characters are still not getting escaped. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please read the `Parameters` section of this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreach arrays don't work by reference by default, you need to tell it to:

```
function escape_all(&$val){
    foreach($val as $key=>&$value){
        $value =  mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
}
```

Also remember that real_escape_string needs a mysql connection to work properly.